# nhibernate burrow and ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, nhibernate-burrow

I using nhibernate burrow for long conversation. I am preparing to migrate project to ASP.NET MVC, but burrow doesn't support MVC.

I trying to change Burrow to work via MVC. But I have no idea what is the best way to do this. I am not sure that HTTP Module is a good way. I think about ActionFilters to initialize conversation.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the httpmodule? It should work with any asp.net framework, be it webforms, monorail or asp.net mvc

Comment: Burrow checks whether the current IHTTPHandler is Page or not. But it's MvcHandler in MVC and if you type *.aspx in url IHTTPHandler is page also At this point can't determine that the controller name is valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

you might wanna look here 
http://blog.pragmasql.com/post/NHibernate-20-Sample-Project-using-NHibernateBurrow-contribution.aspx
for a project that uses nhibernate burrow + asp.net mvc

Comment: I checked the sample. it doesn't use burrow long conversation.